# Row Level Security on Multiple tables/Views

Tags: azure-sql-database, row-level-security

I’m looking for some guidance on implementing multiple row level security policies for different use cases on the same tables/views. Basically, I have a view “ReportView” used for a report which has a column which identifies who the owner of that data is (ADUserName).  Depending on who runs the report, only the owner or their manager etc should be able to see the data.  I also have a view called “Userdetails” which holds all the user details information:
Username, Team, TeamLeaderUserName, Department, Subdepartment, Region etc.

I have created a table value function which accepts a username and returns 1 if the username matches the logged on username.
I’ve then created a security policy which references the tvf, against the UserDetails view passing in the Username Column.

Now if I select from the ReportVeiw and join it to the Userdetails view, then only the rows associated with the user are shown. Brilliant!  Just what I want.
However, the person running the report could be a team leader and so they will want to view the data for all their team. So I created a new security policy that used the same tvf but passed in the TeamLeaderUserName column of the Userdetails view.  Again, this worked and did what I wanted!

However, the problem is, I have multiple use cases for these reports – A single user, a team leader, a manager of a department, sub department, region etc.
I can’t have multiple security policies on the same table/view. I can’t use a lot of “OR” commands in the function as this causes performance issues, so I’m a little confused about how best to implement this.
Should I have lots of views for all the different permutations and I assume, multiple reports for the different use cases?

Comment: You should implement to best practice first, then optimize for performance next. You should not immediately eliminate a solution until you've fully exhausted trying to optimize the performance of it. That being said, when the `OR` clause affects query performance, if applicable, I'll use the `UNION` clause instead and *sometimes* that will help improve execution plans. And that's precisely how I currently implement my different related row-level security use cases within the same function consumed by a single security policy.

Comment: Thanks. I did try with the or clause and without it the query took less than a second, but with it, I gave up after waiting 5 minutes for any results!! I'll try a union which could help.  Thanks.

Comment: No prob! Btw, if you get stuck with optimizing a query, that makes for a good question here on DBA.StackExchange as well. Usually the experienced minds here can take a look and make applicable suggestions that could help improve the performance. So feel free to post a new question (with the execution plan and example query) if you find needing further help.